# Commerce Kickstart Review Overrides Error

Tags: commerce

I want to upgrade Commerce Kickstart (commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.53) to the latest 2.54. Following the upgrade instructions I went to the Structure Features menu to check for overrides and found these are overriden.

```
Commerce Kickstart Blog
Commerce Kickstart Lite Product
Commerce Kickstart Merchandising
Commerce Kickstart Slideshow
Commerce Kickstart User
```

But when I go to Review Overrides, I get these errors.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in features_override_features_export_render_addition() (line 428 of /home/-----/public_html/sw/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/features_override/features_override.export.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in features_override_features_export_render_addition() (line 428 of /home/-----/public_html/sw/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/features_override/features_override.export.inc).
Error: Call to a member function stateVariables() on string in RulesPlugin->availableVariables() (line 740 of /home/-----/public_html/sw/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/rules/includes/rules.core.inc).

First, is there a fix for these errors?
If not, is there any way to know what overrides are actually in place?
In any case, can I proceed with the Commerce Kickstart (commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.54) upgrade?
```

FYI: Running Drupal 7.58 and PHP Version 7.1.16

Thanks

Comment: Workaround is to click on the feature name and it lists all settings for that feature, then Review Overrides gives changes for that feature so I have been able to print the list of changes for each feature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those modules are compatible with PHP 7? We haven't tested nor do we recommend running Commerce Kickstart 2.x in PHP 7 as far as I know.